# Can you use unlimited custom objects in methods?

Tags: java, methods

I've been trying to write a method that takes in an undetermined amount of objects with a **string** and **int** value, but each in an order that makes sense. As far as I understand, these can be accomplished using "..." in methods, for example:

```
public void methodExample(String... a) { }
```

could be called as either`methodExample("a");` or `methodExample("a", "b", "c");`

In addition, if I were to use multiple different types of arguments in an unlimited sense, I would write:

```
public void methodExample(String... a, int... b);
```

Then, I would call it as:`methodExample("a", "b", "c", 1, 2, 3);`

My question is: Is it possible to do this in a format where you can call the method as:`methodExample("a", 1, "b", 2, "c", 3")`

As far as I know, the only way to accomplish this would be to write

```
methodExample(new ExampleObject("a", 1), new ExampleObject("b", 2));
```

Is there a more concise way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Which will force check of types and order inside the method. The `ExmpleObject` approach is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way. Even [java 9's immutable collections](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/269) opts to use your format, so I think there is no other way to accomplish such task.

There are some heated discussion on this topic in this [thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2015-September/035384.html). It also introduces using temporary objects to hold data.

Comment: Glad to be helpful! Please mark my anwser as selected so others can see this question as "finished" and not getting in to see if you are still confused.

Comment: "No way" . well you can if you use Object as the type of the varargs, but obviously that doesn't guarantee type safety.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw That would be the least suggested way though. I really don't think it a good idea... You got a great mess both at call site and in method body.

Comment: @glee8e  you're absolutely correct it is not a good idea hence why I said on my comment "that doesn't guarantee type safety.". I was just suggested there is a way to achieve OPs question but of course, it wouldn't be a good idea to use it.

Comment: @OusmaneMahyDiaw all right, then. But using it in 1) open source projects then project lead will reject your PR 2) commercial projects then you will lose your job 3) academic project then you will fail. It's essentailly "no way" after all.

Comment: What's the reason for not using Object variable types besides type safety? Unless I made a coding mistake myself, would there be any consequences? The code I'm working on isn't for anyone besides me.

Comment: You will have to cast a lot in the method body. And even just sorting things out into their actual type sucks. BTW, *The code I'm working on isn't for anyone besides me* should not be a excuse to write poor code, because *you* will have to maintain the code after you are completed, too. poor code lead to maintainability disaster, which then lead to hours or days wasted on a small bug.